# One adjective for two or more nouns

Tags: adjectives, coordination, conjunction-reduction

Could we use one adjective for two nouns? Is the following sentence correct?

> It has low speed and voltage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It has low speed and voltage

is correct, but ambiguous. It may mean

> It has low speed and low voltage

or

> It has voltage and low speed.

Comment: Agree.  The first may be ambiguous but since 'voltage' on it's own doesn't make much sense, more will assume 'low' applies to both 'speed' and 'voltage'.

Answer (score 1):

Pretend we're starting with these two sentences:

> ​1. It has low speed.
>   ​2. It has low voltage.

Let's put them together with ***and***.

We can delete repeated material from the beginning of the second clause:

> It has low speed **and** it has low voltage.
>   It has low speed **and** <strike>it</strike> has low voltage.
>   It has low speed **and** <strike>it has</strike> low voltage.
>   It has low speed **and** <strike>it has low</strike> voltage.

Any of these would be okay.